# Crystal Reports - Group Header with row details

Tags: excel, crystal-reports, grouping, crystal-reports-2008

I would like to generate a crystal report with multiple groups and each group may have a row of its own which should not be repeated in details section.

```
 Country        REGION      BRANCH      amount1      amount2 

7102                                        .88     .77 

            7758                    


                        7758                0.71      0.33
```

That is Every Branch comes under region and every region comes under country.

Country can have its own amount directly or amount can be associated to region or branch.

Amount associated with country i would like to show it in the group header.

Is that possible. If yes can someone PLEASE guide me.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add multiple groups to your Crystal report. So Group 1 would be Country, Group 2 would be Region, and so on.